# Axes origin of 3d plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

For example I am plotting a 3d data set:

```
data = Transpose@Range[{10, 10, 10}]

{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}, 
 {6, 6, 6}, {7, 7, 7}, {8, 8, 8}, {9, 9, 9}, {10, 10, 
  10}}

ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.03]}, Boxed -> True,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x (mm)", "y (mm)", "z (mm)"}, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

The result is:

[image]

How can I achieve that the origin (0,0,0) is in the lower left edge of the cube (and how can I control on which of the axes the ticks are drawn)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.03]}, Boxed -> True, 
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x (mm)", "y (mm)", "z (mm)"}, 
     ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", AxesEdge -> {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great ... so many options and I did not find this `AxesEdge`.

Comment: What do I have to do if I want to have the origin where the red circle is: https://i.imgur.com/rewwO84.png. I want to see the x-y plane parallel to the screen.

Comment: @mrz You need `{{1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}`. The 2nd sublist means that the y-axis intersects x and z at their low value. The x-axis (first sublist) intersect y axis at high value and z axis at low value